# JavaScript - How to assign user input value to variable inside script

Tags: javascript

Using widget script--http://socialmention.com/tools/-- from Social Mention. Tried to modify by adding input box to allow user to change social media topic (var smSearchPhrase). I created a function [smSearch()] to retrieve user data (smTopic), assign it to a new variable (var newTopic) and then assign that value to var smSearchPhrase. The assignment does not work.

The function appears to work based on values observed via alerts, however, I cannot figure out how to assign the value from var newTopic to var smSearchPhrase inside the script. I experimented by placing script inside the function, but that didn't work either. Any assistance is appreciated.

If I failed to include all necessary information, please advise.  Thanks for any assistance.

HTML:

```
<form>
   <label for="smTopic">Enter topic:</label>
   <input type="text" id="smTopic">
   <button onclick="smSearch()">Submit</button>
   <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Function: (includes alerts to check values)

```
function smSearch(){ 
   var newTopic=document.getElementById("smTopic").value;
       if(newTopic === ""){
          alert("Please enter new social media topic.");                                                  
       }else{
          alert("New topic: " + newTopic);
          smSearchPhrase = newTopic; 
          alert("Value of smSearchPhrase: " + smSearchPhrase);
}
```

Script: var smSearchPhrase in original has value assigned, e.g. var smSearchPhrase = 'social mention';

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      // search phrase (replace this)
      var smSearchPhrase;
      // title (optional)
      var smTitle = 'Realtime Buzz';
      // items per page
      var smItemsPerPage = 7;
      // show or hide user profile images
      var smShowUserImages = true;
      // widget font size in pixels
      var smFontSize = 11;
      // height of the widget
      var smWidgetHeight = 800;
      // sources (optional, comment out for "all")
      //var smSources = ['twitter', 'facebook', 'googleblog', 'identica'];
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://socialmention.s3.amazonaws.com/buzz_widget/buzz.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? How doesn't it work. It looks like it does assign the value. When are you trying to show the value in smSearchPhrase.

Comment: Thank you Bjorn for your reply.  I cannot get the value from the input box (smTopic) assigned to smSearchPhrase in the script. For me, it works only when I manually enter a value for smSearchPhrase, e.g. var smSearchPhrase = 'stackoverflow'; I hope that answers your question. Thanks! -Jim

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out, adding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your form is submitting back to the backend, you need to stop the form from doing that by returning `false` from onsubmit or canceling the event.

So this should work:

```
<form onsubmit="return smSearch();">
   <label for="smTopic">Enter topic:</label>
   <input type="text" id="smTopic">
   <button>Submit</button>
   <input type="reset">
</form>
```

And return false in your JavaScript:

```
function smSearch(){ 
       var newTopic=document.getElementById("smTopic").value;
       if(newTopic === ""){
          alert("Please enter new social media topic.");                                                  
       }else{
          alert("New topic: " + newTopic);
          smSearchPhrase = newTopic; 
          alert("Value of smSearchPhrase: " + smSearchPhrase);
       }
       return false;
}
```

Personally I'd use preventDefault() on the event argument (not shown here), but that only works across all browsers when you also include a JavaScript library like jQuery as some versions of IE use a bubble property on the event or something.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn. I modified the HTML to return smSearch() onsubmit and the function by returning false. The alerts indicate that smSearchPhrase was successfully assigned the value from the input box, but it still isn't working.  Is the script from SocialMention with var smSearchPhrase; ok? Thanks for your help. -- Jim

Comment: What isn't working? What did you want it to do? What isn't it doing? Thanks.

Comment: I uploaded the file for you to look at. http://www.webmediapartners.com/contact/social-media-buzz.php. Thanks for your assistance!  -- Jim

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work:  http://www.webmediapartners.com/contact/buzz.php. Perhaps you can navigate from the home page: http://www.webmediapartners.com/. The link is the last one under Web Services.